# what is HttpResponse.OutputStream Property in Asp.net?

Tags: asp.net

I read Microsoft explanation about what is OutputStream Property! but i really don't understand what is this mean! someone can give me more explanation about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [OutputStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.outputstream%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is mechanism by which you can transmit content to the client in binary form such as files. This contrasts with the [Output](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.output%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property which enables text-based content to be sent to the client.

If you look at the MSDN documentation for both properties, you will see the `OutputStream` is an implementation of `System.IO.Stream` which enables you to work with objects as a sequence of bytes, which is usually the most efficient way of moving file content around in .NET. `Output` is an implementation of `System.IO.TextWriter`.